# Issue with Travis-ci, unable to fetch dependencies Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, travis-ci

I'm having trouble getting my project to build on travis. it's written in swift 4 which travis should support. It seems like there is an issue fetching dependencies but "It works on my machine." `swift build` and `swift test` at least so i'm having a hard time getting around as to what the issue might be on travis' side.

Has anyone here dealt with a similar issue and knows what's wrong ?

YAML

```
os:
  - osx
language: swift
osx_image: xcode9
script:
  - swift build
  - swift test
```

Output

```
11.10s$ swift build
Cloning https://github.com/valdirunars/BigIntCompress.git
error: terminated(128): git clone --shared/Users/travis/build/valdirunars/BioSwift/.build/repositories/BigIntCompress.git-5255985680209734865/Users/travis/build/valdirunars/BioSwift/.build/checkouts/BigIntCompress.git-5255985680209734865
error: product dependency 'BigInt' not found
error: product dependency 'BigIntCompress' not found
The command "swift build" exited with 1.
0.58s$ swift test
Cloning https://github.com/valdirunars/BigIntCompress.git
error: terminated(128): git clone --shared     /Users/travis/build/valdirunars/BioSwift/.build/repositories/BigIntCompress.git-5255985680209734865 /Users/travis/build/valdirunars/BioSwift/.build/checkouts/BigIntCompress.git-5255985680209734865
error: product dependency 'BigInt' not found
error: product dependency 'BigIntCompress' not found
The command "swift test" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out travis fails on fetching dependencies when it's in the `script`stage (in the .yml)

The solution was to add an `install` tag where all dependencies are fetched.

```
os:
  - osx
language: swift
osx_image: xcode9
install: swift package update
script:
  - swift build
  - swift test
```